# Why does my program crash when I try to call methods for my button?

Tags: android, button, graphics, view, crash

So, I'm writing a program for Android. Right now, I'm in a class called GraphicsView, which extends View and implements View.OnClickListener. I have created a button mLeft, that is supposed to move an object to the left when pressed. I am trying to get this to display on the bottom left of the screen. In my constructor for GraphicsView I have the code:

```
mLeft = new Button (context.getApplicationContext ());
mLeft.setId (1); // wasn't sure what else to set for an id, I only did that to see if it would fix anything
mLeft.setOnClickListener (this);
```

And in my onDraw I have:

```
mLeft.draw (canvas);
```

With just this code, the program runs fine, and when I go to the activity that uses GraphicsView it works totally fine, except for the face that the button doesn't show up anywhere.

I also have this doe in my constructor, right below the setOnClickListener:

```
mLeft.setX (0);
mLeft.setY (mDisplay.getHeight () - 64);
mLeft.setHeight (64);
mLeft.setWidth (64);
mLeft.setBackgroundColor (80000000);
mLeft.setText ("<");
```

Whenever I have this code in there, and I go to that activity, the program crashes. I do have onClick in there, and other than "Button mLeft" at the top, this is all of the code I have associated with this button. Basically, it looks like the program is crashing whenever I try to call any of those methods from Button. I have tried commenting these out to there there is only one of them present in the code at a time, so I know that each of them individually could kill the program.

The LogCat says: "12-04 15:11:03.581: I/dalvikvm(2692): Could not find method android.widget.Button.setX, referenced from method edu.pacificu.cs.Views.GraphicsView."

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Button.setX ... API lvl 11 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `mLeft = new Button (context.getApplicationContext ());`

Don't do that. Use `new Button(context)`, and then only if `context` is an `Activity`. Never use `getApplicationContext()` unless you know *exactly why* you are using it.

> The LogCat says: "12-04 15:11:03.581: I/dalvikvm(2692): Could not find method android.widget.Button.setX, referenced from method edu.pacificu.cs.Views.GraphicsView."

As @Selvin points out, you appear to be running this application on Android 2.x, using a method (`setX()`) that does not exist on Android 2.x. `setX()` and `setY()` are mostly for animation effects (e.g., slides). The X/Y/Z position of your `View` is determined by its container (layout) and that container's configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much :) So the button will have methods to set the layout position, width and height?

Comment: @TaylorMatyasz: As I wrote, the X/Y/Z position of your `View` is determined by its container (layout) and that container's configuration. Please work through some Android programming tutorials and samples to see this in action, as the *vast* majority of these samples use ordinary containers (e.g., `LinearLayout`, to put widgets in a row or column).

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I've figured this out now.